# Android application upload error

Tags: android

i'm having a hard time uploading my upgraded version to the developers console. I've incremented the versionCode and the versionName and i used the same details to exporting the apk file as i did before.

when i try to upload the new file all it says that there's a unexpected error and asks me to choose another file.

does anyone have any hints or even know how to fix this error? would the problem be in my manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="kev.harris"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/man21"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:debuggable="false">
    <activity
        android:name=".AssignmentActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="kev.harris.MAINMENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- makes it so that the code is recognised but is to run in the background -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainGame"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="kev.harris.MainGame" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- makes it so that the code is recognised but is to run in the background -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Savefile"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- saving stuff -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Continues"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="kev.harris.CONTINUES" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- makes it so that the code is recognised but is to run in the background -->
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- continuing -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Dead"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewGame"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- used for the choice between male and female -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Male"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- for choosing the standard or custom picture -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CMPicture"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- for the male custom picture -->
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MPicture"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- for the male normal picture -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Female"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- for the female choice of picture -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CfPicture"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- for the female custom picture -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FPicture"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <!-- for the female normal picture -->
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest?  Sometimes the Dev Console is buggy or the servers go down too, but it's probably good to check your manifest

Comment: i just added the whole manifest there. :)

Comment: looks ok, might want to add a targetSdk, but looks like a correct manifest at a glance

Comment: i'll add that in :) and i appreciate you looking at my manifest :)

Answer (score 0):

R you including .apk extension with your file name.When you are exporting.

Comment: i've got the .apk extension at the end the file name.